# end Kernel panic - not syncing error when installing 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I have 16.04 installed on an old HP a1630n AMD desktop. Downloaded and burned 18.04 ISO to DVD. During boot up from DVD I get the error [ end Kernel panic - not syncing... ]

Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix?

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of your iso file by comparing its hash sums after downloading? Did you verify the DVD got burned correctly? Can you try selecting the "Check disk for defects" option in the DVD's boot menu?

Comment: How do I verify the DVD was burned correctly? When booting from the DVD no menu appears, just a text screen with part of the installation process and the kernel panic error. I can try burning the ISO to the DVD again and turn on any validation, if that will help.